# scoring of Term vs. Terms query different

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, term-query

I am retrieving documents by filtering and using a `term` query to apply a score.
The query should match all animals having a specified color - the more colors are matched, the higher the score of a doc. Strange thing is, **`term` and `terms` query result in a different scoring.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"terms": {"color": ["brown","darkbrown"] } },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

should be the same like using

```
{"term": {"color": {"value": "brown"} } },
{"term": {"color": {"value": "darkbrown"} } }
```

Query no. 1 gives me the exact same score for a document whether 1 or 2 terms are matched. The latter of course returns a higher score, if more colors are matched.

As stated by the [coordination factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/practical-scoring-function.html#coord) the returned score should be higher if more terms are matched. Therefore these two queries should result in the same score - or is because `term` queries do not analyze the search term?

My field is indexed as text. Strings are indexed as an "array" of strings, e.g. `"brown","darkbrown"`

Answer (score 3):

**Difference between term vs terms query:**

- **Term query** return documents that contain one or more exact term in a provided field.
- The **terms query** is the same as the term query, except you can search for multiple values.
- **Warning:** Avoid using the term query for text fields.

As far your this part is concerned

> or is because term queries do not analyze the search term?

Yes, It is because the search term does not analyze the term searched. It just matches the exact search term.

Comment: So I will have to use multiple term queries if I want my score to be higher, when there are several colors matching?

Comment: if there are sever colors to be matched then best practice is to use terms as it is for matching with multiple search terms.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. More colors matched -> higher score. But this apparently does not work for `terms` query - no matter how many colors are matched, score is always 1\0. It works though if I use a `term` query

Comment: "Yes, It is because the search term do not analyze the term searched. It just matches the exact search term." - could you please clarify this